# Using a mixed effects regression model for between-subject design?

Tags: regression, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I have data from a between-subject experiment, where every subject was assigned to one of the two conditions, and completed varying number of trials (as much as they wanted). Number of trials is between 3 and 15, roughly Gaussian distribution with mean=6.

I'm analyzing the effect of condition on effort spent on each trial (measured by the number of steps taken in each trial). Now, should I include  random effect of subjects (considering that each subject has only experienced one condition)?

Comment: You question would be improved by clicking the "edit" link in its lower left and expanding to describe: What is the distribution of number of trials? How is effort measured?